# How to find which html elements have a recently changed background-color using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

Just wanting some advice on how I might go about this part of my code:

In my code I have randomly changed the background-color of a bunch of different divs, and the only thing the divs have in them is a letter (working)
I want to then return which divs were changed os i can monitor if the user clicks them etc.

How might I go about finding which elements have been 'selected'?

Code so far:

```
function generatePattern() {
    let key = document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-letter");
    let number = document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-number");
    
    console.log(key);

    for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        let boolean = Math.random() >= 0.75;

        if (boolean == true) {
            key[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
            key[i].style.color = "black";
        } else if (boolean == false) {
            key[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
            key[i].style.color = "white";
        };
    }
}
```

(ignore the number variable)

I have tried with query selector, although I couldn't find a specific example of how to layout the syntax.

Comment: Why are you not just storing them in an array? Also adding and removing a class would be a lot simpler.

Comment: I tried adding and removing classes, but I already have a class on them, so I don't know how to add a class when I already have one.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

> os i can monitor if the user clicks them etc

If you need to know when the user clicks the elements, just use an event listener like such:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-letter").addEventListener("click", function() {

     /*Do Whatever you need to do when the user clicks the element*/

})

document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-number").addEventListener("click", function() {

     /*Do Whatever you need to do when the user clicks the element*/

})
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-number")` does not return an element on which to call `addEventListener` Did you mean to iterate throught the html collection?

Answer (score 0):

So push the element onto an array

```
function generatePattern() {
    let key = document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-letter");
    let number = document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-number");
    
    var activeElems = []

    for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        let boolean = Math.random() >= 0.75;
        var elem = key[i];

        if (boolean == true) {
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            elem.style.color = "black";
            activeElems.push(elem);
        } else {
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            elem.style.color = "white";
        };
    }

  console.log(activeElems);
}
```

Code could be made a lot cleaner with just toggling a class.

```js
function generatePattern() {
  const keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keyboard-letter");

  const activeElems = []

  keys.forEach(function (elem) {
    const isActive = Math.random() >= 0.75;
    elem.classList.toggle('active', isActive);
    if (isActive) activeElems.push(elem);
  });
  
  console.log(activeElems);
    
}

generatePattern()
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 40px);
   grid-gap: 0px;
}

div.keyboard-letter {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

div.keyboard-letter.active {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="keyboard-letter">1</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">2</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">3</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">4</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">5</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">6</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">7</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">8</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">9</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">10</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">11</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">12</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">13</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">14</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">15</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">16</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">17</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">18</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">19</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">20</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add mutation observer for your container and need to change a code little bit to change the style using setAttribute

```
// call this function onload
function startOb(params) {
            const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
            // target container to watch     
            const list = document.querySelector(`#container`);
            // options
            const config = {
                attributes: true,
                childList: true,
                characterData: true,
                subtree: true,
            };
            // instance
            const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {

                    if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
                        console.log("mutation =", mutation);
                        console.log(`The \`${mutation.attributeName}\` attribute was modified.`);
                        // console.log("list style =", list.style);
                        
                    }
                });
            });
            observer.observe(list, config);
        }



          function generatePattern() {
            let key = document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-letter");
            let number = document.getElementsByClassName("keyboard-number");

            console.log(key);

            for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
                let boolean = Math.random() >= 0.75;

                if (boolean == true) {
                    key[i].setAttribute(`style`, `backgroundColor: white; color: black`);
                    
                } else if (boolean == false) {
                    key[i].setAttribute(`style`, `backgroundColor: black; color: white`);
                };
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explaination :** `active` is a CSS class which changes the `background` to `black` and `color` to `white`. Now, I have used a button so that, you can see how changes are happening. Whenever the button is clicked, the forEach loop runs for each `.keyboard-letter` element. When `check` is false, the `active` class is to be added. So it checks, if it is already present. If it is already present, nothing happens, but when it absent, the `active` class is added, and that element is pushed in the array `activeElems`. What happens, when `check` is true, is will be understandable.

Click the button to find out the elements which changed their CSS :

```js
var activeElems;
var firstRun = true;

function generatePattern() {

  activeElems = [];
  const keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keyboard-letter");
  keys.forEach(function(elem) {
    const check = Math.random() >= 0.75;
    if (!check) {
      if (!elem.classList.contains("active")) {
        elem.classList.add("active");
        activeElems.push(elem);
      }
    } else {
      if (elem.classList.contains("active")) {
        elem.classList.remove("active");
        activeElems.push(elem);
      }
    }
  });
  if(firstRun == true) firstRun = false;
  else{
    console.log(activeElems);
    console.log(activeElems.length);
  }
}

generatePattern();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.keyboard-letter {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="keyboard-letter">1</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">2</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">3</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">4</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">5</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">6</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">7</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">8</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">9</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">10</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">11</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">12</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">13</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">14</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">15</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">16</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">17</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">18</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">19</div>
  <div class="keyboard-letter">20</div>
  <button onClick="generatePattern()">Button</button>
</div>
```